# Computed Setter Value based on existing value - WPF

Tags: wpf, triggers, setter

Currently have a setup as below:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="rectName" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>                                            
    <Setter TargetName="rectName" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>                    
</Trigger>
```

i.e. The trigger changes the Stroke and Thickness of a Rectangle to Red and 2 on MouseOver.
But this must happen only when the Rectangle's Stroke is Black (Few rectangles have transparent stroke)

Is there any way to put this condition on Setter? I'm looking at a less intrusive way of accomplishing this. Any leads?

Is there a construct something like below:

```
<Setter TargetName="rectName" Property="Stroke" Value="If Black Then Black Else Red"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here this will work, note however this code will throw a stack overflow exception because of the change of the changing colors when you mouse over ie red black red black and so on :/ I would just suggest some other way to keep track of the rect state, maybe a variable in the ViewModel that keeps track of the state and and in the code replace:

```
<Condition  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Stroke}" Value="Black" />
```

With something like:

```
<Condition Binding="{Path=RectState}" Value="True" />
```

Otherwise this will crash :) (Sorry writing this in a rush)

```
 <Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,152,0,0" Name="rectangle1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" >
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>                      
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Stroke}" Value="Black" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can achieve this using MultiTrigger (code below not tested, but should be close enough)</strike>

```
 <Style.Triggers>
     <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
            <Condition Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter TargetName="rectName" Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
        <Setter TargetName="rectName" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
     </MultiTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: It gives an error `'Stroke' property cannot be set from a property trigger and appear in the trigger's condition at the same time.`

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. I think you will have to use a valueconverter instead =(